# MSOutlook - Проблема с переносом параметров учетных записей (2003->2013)

Tags: outlook

Вопрос:
я пользовался MS Outlook 2003, и в нем, у меня были заригистрированы 11 ящиков (11 учетных записей),
 когда я перешел на MS Outlook 2013, возникла проблема,
 перенести в него, информацию о учетных ящиках.
 Каким образом это можно сделать?

Из старой информации – осталось только *.pst - файлы ящиков (например `Outlook...@gmail.com-00000012.pst" или "Outlook...@yahoo.com-00000016.pst`) и 
 информация реестра (как хотел сделать по варианту http://habrahabr.ru/post/68184/ или http://updatepc.ru/perenos-microsoft-outlook.html)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\OMI Account Manager 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook   
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\%версия офиса%\Outlook\Options
```

Но нечего не получилось.

Я уже в файле реестра `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\%версия офиса%\Outlook\Options` и версию менял и обратно запускал. (т.к. старая версия у меня была "11.0", а новая версия outlook уже "15.0")

Просматривая например ссылки на сайте https://support.office.com/ru-ru/art...rs=ru-RU&ad=RU. Ничего внятного так и не нашел.

Экспортировать этот файл, как файл данных - не вариант - данные просматриваются, а толку? **Учетные записи же НЕ добавляются при этом**.

Заранее спасибо.

P.S.
- Да ОС, тоже изменилась: с Windows XP на Windows 8.1
- и название системного диска также поменялось: с "Н:" на "С:"

Comment: Третья ссылка не открывается

Comment: В третьей ссылке, также написано о реестре (все пишит об одном но у меня всеравно не получается)